# how to disable launching some applications?

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe2, delphi-2010

Is there a way to **prevent some applications to be launched** ?

1) ex: I don't want users to launch notepad.exe : is that possible ?

2) Is that possible to forbid all applications to be launched except "notepad.exe" ?

Thanks

Comment: lunch is not the same as launch

Comment: This has little to do with Delphi nor programming in general. Seems like it has to do with user rights in Windows, perhaps kiosk mode. If no one is allowed to launch notepad, just delete it.

Comment: Yes, possible with Domain policy. Has nothing to with [delphi], tho

Comment: You can try using a [File System Filter Driver](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/hardware/gg462968.aspx)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An approach could be

```
procedure KillProcess(hWindowHandle: HWND);
var
  hprocessID: INTEGER;
  processHandle: THandle;
  DWResult: DWORD;
begin
  SendMessageTimeout(hWindowHandle, WM_CLOSE, 0, 0,
    SMTO_ABORTIFHUNG or SMTO_NORMAL, 5000, DWResult);

  if isWindow(hWindowHandle) then
  begin
    // PostMessage(hWindowHandle, WM_QUIT, 0, 0);

    { Get the process identifier for the window}
    GetWindowThreadProcessID(hWindowHandle, @hprocessID);
    if hprocessID <> 0 then
    begin
      { Get the process handle }
      processHandle := OpenProcess(PROCESS_TERMINATE or PROCESS_QUERY_INFORMATION,
        False, hprocessID);
      if processHandle <> 0 then
      begin
        { Terminate the process }
        TerminateProcess(processHandle, 0);
        CloseHandle(ProcessHandle);
      end;
    end;
  end;
end;
```

And you have a process with timer, thread or what you want. that executes

```
KillProcess(FindWindow('notepad',nil));
```